# Mount Windows shared filder to AIX

Tags: unix, aix, mount, shared-directory

I have a shared folder on Windows 2008.  We are now trying to mount this folder at a client site on Unix AIX 5.3.  But we do not know how to do it.  What is the mount command and options? 
They are using Putty.

Now I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Unix, so please try and keep the Unix bits simple for me :-)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two options

1) The easiest would be to install the bos.cifs fileset and use smit to mount the share as a filesystem: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1fileset-1244257370

2) I would not recommend this for "newbies", but you may have better luck getting this to work by installing samba: www.samba.org